# Uniqueness of PDE via energy functional

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Assume the pde:

$$
u_{tt}(t,x) = c^2u_{xx}(t,x) + \sigma u_{txx}(t,x) -\mu u_{t}(t,x), \quad x \in [0,L], t>0
$$
$$
u_x(t,0) = u(t,L) = 0
$$
$$
u(0,x) = \phi(x), u_t(0,x) = \theta(x), x\in[0,L]
$$
$$
\phi(L) = \theta(L) = 0, \phi'(0) = \theta '(0) = 0.
$$
and the energy functional:
$$
V(t) = \int_{0}^L\frac12u_t^2(t,x) + \frac{c^2}{2}u_x^2(t,x)dx
$$

To prove uniqueness we'll assume $u_1$, $u_2$ are both solutions and then define $u$ as $u := u_1 - u_2$.

Then, we observe that 
$$u(0,x) = u_1(0,x) - u_2(0,x) = \phi(x) - \phi(x) \equiv 0$$
$$u_t(0,x) = u_{1,t}(0,x) - u_{2,t}(0,x) = \theta(x) - \theta(x) \equiv 0$$

So $u_x(0,x) = u_t(0,x) = 0$. Thus we have

$$
V(0) = \int_0^L 0 \, dx = 0
$$

Also, I have already shown that $V(t) \leq V(0)$ so

$$
V(t) \leq 0
$$

and since $V(t) \geq 0$, we have $V(t) \equiv 0$. Then since the integrand is non-negative:

$$
\frac12u_t^2(t,x) + \frac{c^2}{2}u_x^2(t,x) \equiv 0 \quad \quad (1)
$$

### **Question:**

Does $(1)$ guarantee that $u \equiv 0$ and why?

Comment: Is it because $u_t(t,x) = u_x(t,x) \equiv 0$ suggest $u(t,x)$ is a constant and due to the boundary conditions is identically $0$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You could write the argument up as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @RhysSteele Another quick question:  $u = u_1 - u_2$ is itself a solution of the pde, right? (at least I assumed it was when using the functional).

Comment: $u_1 - u_2$ solves the PDE with $0$ boundary conditions, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation

$$
\frac12u_t^2(t,x) + \frac{c^2}{2}u_x^2(t,x) = 0
$$

suggests that

$$
u_t(t,x) \equiv 0 \quad \text{and} \quad u_x(t,x) \equiv 0
$$

and thus $u(t,x) = \text{constant}$. Finally, the boundary condition $u(t,L) = 0$ implies that
$$
u(t,x) \equiv 0 
$$

and thus $u_1 \equiv u_2.$